# How to access Microsoft dynamics crm in java using rest api?

Tags: api, rest, crm, microsoft-dynamics

How to get access token for accessing from external applications?

I want to access microsoft active dynamics crm using rest api from java.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to access..
Doing a Request for example.. you can already start like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var strClientUrl = this.GetClientUrl();
 //alert(strClientUrl);
 req.open("POST", strClientUrl, false)
 req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
 req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
 var requestXML = this.getRequestXML(requestName, ParameterXML);
 req.send(requestXML);
```

Comment: ☝️ This example is a SOAP call, so not the REST API that the question refers to.